# Is there a performance cost using razor views vs embeded code in class controller?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

After the request had been compiled and called a few time, is there a performance difference between :

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View("~/Views/Index.cshtml");
}
```

And

```
public ActionResult Index() {
    var sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.Append("<html><body>Bla bla bla bla</body></html>");
    return Content(sb.ToString());
}
```

I feel at use there is one.

Is the compiled code resulting from Razor parsing aproximatively the same of using a stringbuilder or totally different ?

Comment: Why don't you test the performance difference yourself and find out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer depends on what content is contained in the view. I used `Glimpse` to measure the time to render an `Index()` method, once using `View()` and another returning `Content()` with the sample HTML you gave. In both cases, the time was about equal - roughly 300 - 400ms each. Once I put some HTML in the view though, it took a bit longer to complete the request, say 600 - 700ms.

Overall I'd say that using `Content()` might be a bit quicker, since there is no Razor parser involved when returning it.

Comment: Definitly quicker, I installed Glimpse as you mentionned and with a complex Razor rendering vs the same code rendered along with computation inside a routine building a StringBuilder we're talking about at least 2x times quicker for StringBuilder pure content rendering.